# Confluent platform on Windows without Docker

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am runnning Kafka and Zookeeper in Windows with below commands:

```
zookeeper-server-start.bat config/zookeeper.properties
kafka-server-start.bat config/server.properties.
```

**1. How can I run schema registry on Windows without docker?**

I've gone through confluent documentation which says "Windows users can download and use the ZIP and TAR archives, but must run the JAR files directly."
I've downloaded confluent tar archive and able to see bin, etc, lib, share, src folders.

**2.where are the jars located? How can I run Jars directly?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In simple words the answer is "no". If you will check Confluent distributions, there is no distributions for windows available.

There are other options like "cygwin" or my favourite "ubuntu on windows" link - https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6?activetab=pivot:overviewtab.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Varun is correct. Confluent Platform is not supported on Windows. You may be able to get the different JARs to work but by far the easiest is to run it under Docker or a VM.